# JavaScript: Hide scrollbar before page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a preloader that will be shown while the page is loading. And I use `window.addEventListener("load", function()` to make it hidden once the page is loaded.

I wanna hide the scrollbar while the page is loading. The question is that if I put the code `overflow: hidden;` in the function, the scrollbar will only be hidden after the page is fully loaded, but I want it to be hidden before and during the page is loading ( when the preloader is showing ).

If you run the script below, you will see the scrollbar is hidden because the page is already loaded as there is only one `<p>` HTML element which I use it for illustration purpose, if the page loads long, then you will see the scrollbar will still be shown while loading.

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("container");

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto"
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
}

P {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: visible;
}

.loader1{
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border: 3px solid  rgba(255,255,255, .7);
    top: 28%;
    top: calc(50% - 43px);
    left: 35%;
    left: calc(50% - 43px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: loader1 3s linear infinite; animation: loader1 3s linear infinite;
}

.loader1:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader1{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes loader1{
    0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: I don't know if its work: Hide all elements by default, except the one which should be visible and when then page is loaded, show all elements on page except the element which was initaly visible.

Comment: @Reporter This is a great idea! I'll try it out. Thank you so much

Comment: @Reporter But with this method, I'll have to wrap all elements into one div and give a class to that div, then create a function to hide the element by `quarySelectorAll`. If not it will be very time consuming for me to hide all the elements of all pages one by one manually

Comment: You can give each html element a css class or a style attribute.

Comment: @Reporter It will be easier to wrap all the elements into one div. Then, hide that div only. It's also making the HTML size smaller because I only add one class and one div instead of adding a class to every single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added multiple

now you can check overflow will hidden until page loaded

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("container");
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = "none";}, 1000);
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
}

P {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: visible;
}

.loader1{
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border: 3px solid  rgba(255,255,255, .7);
    top: 28%;
    top: calc(50% - 43px);
    left: 35%;
    left: calc(50% - 43px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: loader1 3s linear infinite; animation: loader1 3s linear infinite;
}

.loader1:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader1{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes loader1{
    0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use DOMContentLoaded instead of load

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("container");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto"
  }, 1000)
})
```

Comment: What is the difference to javascript code snippet in question?

Comment: Instead of 'load' inside the eventListener replace it with 'DOMContentLoaded' cause DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded

Comment: Please edit your question with you recommended change. You can do it by clicking on the edit link underneath your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var loader = document.getElementById("container");

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        loader.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto"
    }, 2000)
    })
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what this code does and why it works, that increases the value of your answer drastically. -- Also, your answer looks a lot like another already posted answer posted before this one. Consider upvoting answers instead of posting a similar solution. Hope it helps :)